# How I can bind background color of ion-button in ionic 4

Tags: bind, ionic4

I need dynamic colored button in ionic4.
This is my code, but not working

```
<ion-button [style.--background]="colorVarialble">Buttton</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do by following way

**IONIC 4**

```
  <ion-button style="--background:red">Red</ion-button> // replace your color
```

**IONIC 3**

```
<button ion-button [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'red'}">Butttons</button> //replace your color
```

[Live Demo in v3](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vnkwqh?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, In my case, the `colorVarialble` is dynamic, **is not Countable**. for example, '#000011', '#992233', etc.

Comment: I need use variable instead **red**

Comment: Hi i have given color="<name>", it works fine. But when I click on the button it becomes white in color( has focus on it). When I tap outside it goes back to normal button.

Answer (score 6):

You can use like this:

variables.css

```
 --ion-color-btn: #ef5365;
```

create class in your home.page.scss

```
.btncolor {
  --background: var(--ion-color-btn);
}
```

and after add class in your button:

```
<ion-button shape="round" class="btncolor">
  Get Started
</ion-button>
```

hope it help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also just do it like this:

```
ion-button {
--background: #e95e28;
}
```

Comment: This isn't dynamic